# How can I get FaceTime to output sound configuration of audio midi multi output device?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, facetime

I have MacBook Air and I am trying to set up so that when I am making a FaceTime audio call, both myself and another (hearing impaired) person can listen on their own stream - the hearing impaired person on headphones, myself using either onboard sound or earbuds in the headphone jack.

I set up a multi output device in audio midi, and it works fine with any streaming media or sound file. When I attempt to use the configuration from FaceTime, it will only output to one device, and will not output the multi output configuration.

The multi output device I have set up is comprised of usb plantronics blackwire headphones and the internal speakers.

According to the documentation I have read, FaceTime should recognize the multi output device, in one of two ways: either as a menu option from the video menu in FaceTime, or if the multi output device is set in system preferences, through selecting ‘system settings’ in the FaceTime video  output menu.

FaceTime does recognize the configuration, and offers it as a menu item under the video menu output selections. Frustratingly, however, it does not work. Only one device will play sound, whether I configure through system preferences or select the multi-output device directly.

It occurs to me that this may be a bus power problem, but I don’t know how I could confirm this, or how I might workaround if it is indeed the issue.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not something I've ever tried, but perhaps have a look at the free trial of [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) or even the more comprehensive [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) to see if it can avoid this issue. If it can't, there's a high likelihood it can't be done by any method.

Comment: "High likelihood it can't be done by any method" is what I have concluded as well. SoundFlower, SoundSource, and Audio Hyjack are all recording methods, not live streaming sound applications, so they will not work for this particular requirement.

Comment: Audio Hijack is "the best" [really] route anything to anything app there is at consumer-level, the recorder is almost secondary. [No affiliation, just a long-time user of Rogue Amoeba stuff] SoundSource is a much simpler 'gimme this output for this app'. Their pro-level router is Loopback, but that's usually beyond budget for most consumers. SoundFlower was absorbed into Rogue Amoeba from Cycling'74 a long time ago, the tricksy re-router part was originally called Soundflowerbed, but that hasn't worked for many years.

Comment: I cannot test this actually works [because I never use facetime], but this is how simple the Audio Hijack 'map' should be to route FaceTime to two outputs - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AevSE.png